# Routes in Zend Framewrok

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I'm just starting to work on site with CMS based on Zend. Let's say there are routes specified in routes.ini file, and one of them looks like this:

```
routes.news.route                = "/news/:nice/*"  
routes.news.defaults.module  = "default"   
routes.news.defaults.controller  = "news"  
routes.news.defaults.action      = "item"  
routes.news.reverse              = "/news/%s/*"
```

And it works just fine. But how to edit this code to disable this route if `:nice` will be for example `page-number`

So, what I want is :

```
routes.news.route                = "/news/(if !(:nice == page-number){ :nice}/*"
```

Is that even understandable ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so one can apply if and buts within a route rule. Instead of this way you can use below mentioned solution.

1. In your action check the value of parameter `nice`
2. If it is `page-number` then programatically throw `404` exception.
3. else continue execution of rest of your code.

   ```
   public function testAction() {
       if($this->getRequest()->getParam('nice') == 'page-number') {
           throw new Zend_Controller_Action_Exception('Your message here', 404);
       }
       //Rest of the Code goes here...
   }
   ```

If you will call `http://yourserverpath.com/index/test/nice/page-number` then it will show `404` page and for any other value it will show your original page.